# Como configurar usuário administrador e usuário comum no Firebase

Tags: firebase, angular

Tenho um sistema web que sera utilizado por dois tipos diferentes de usuários, o administrador e o comum.

Há algumas opções que serão apenas disponibilizadas para o administrador (por exemplo, registrar novos usuários). Como que eu faria essa configuração utilizando o firebase?  já que o gerenciamento de usuários do próprio é composto por apenas 'login' e 'senha' e não me oferece possibilidade para adicionar novos campos como por exemplo o 'user type'.

Já li a documentação do firebase e não existe referencia a isso na própria.

Comment: Sua pergunta não é clara, exatamente para que contexto se destina o sistema (mobile, web)? Isso é sobre um sistema de login ou sobre administração e autenticação no Firebase? Perguntas "genéricas" tendem a receber "respostas genéricas"... isso vai na contra-mão da comunidade q busca trazer um partilhamento de conhecimento mais "qualificado".

Comment: Se for só no Firebase talvez ajude: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users

Comment: Olá @LauroMoraes, editei a pergunta de forma que fique mais detalhada.

Answer (score 5):

O [Firebase Auth](http://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) permite apenas 'login' e 'senha' como você disse, mas a [Realtime Database](http://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) e o [Cloud Firestore](http://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) permitem que você guarde muito mais que isso.

Ao criar um usuario, guarde os seus dados num dos serviços de base de dados (Realtime Db ou Firestore) através do uid do usuario logado. Para pegar esse uid é só utilizar:

```
var uid = firebase.auth.currentUser.uid;
```

E então você pode armazenar na Realtime Database com o tipo de usuario:

```
firebase.database.ref('usuarios').child(uid).set({
     login:login,
     senha:senha,
     userType:"Administrador"
});
```

Tendo os dados do usuário armazenados, fica mais fácil de você criar condições para verificar qual utilizador tem acesso à determinada opção do seu sistema.

Comment: Para conhecer melhor a realtime database recomendo [este artigo](https://medium.com/android-dev-moz/firebasesql-4ee3d26a3d15)